# One foreach loop and two arrays

Tags: php, html

I have a little issue with my foreach loop and can't find the mistake.

**first array**

```
$gemeinden = [$barsbek_G, $barsbek_U, $barsbek_F, $bendfeld_G, $bendfeld_U, $bendfeld_F, $brodersdorf_G, $brodersdorf_U, $brodersdorf_F, $fahren_G, $fahren_U, $fahren_F, $fiefbergen_G, $fiefbergen_U, $fiefbergen_F, $hoehndorf_G, $hoehndorf_U, $hoehndorf_F, $koehn_G, $koehn_U, $koehn_F, $krokau_G, $krokau_U, $krokau_F, $krummbek_G, $krummbek_U, $krummbek_F, $laboe_G, $laboe_U, $laboe_F, $lutterbek_G, $lutterbek_U, $lutterbek_F, $passade_G, $passade_U, $passade_F, $prasdorf_G, $prasdorf_U, $prasdorf_F, $probst_G, $probst_U, $probst_F, $schoenberg_G, $schoenberg_U, $schoenberg_F, $stakendorf_G, $stakendorf_U, $stakendorf_F, $stein_G, $stein_U, $stein_F, $stoltenberg_G, $stoltenberg_U, $stoltenberg_F, $wendtorf_G, $wendtorf_U, $wendtorf_F, $wisch_G, $wisch_U, $wisch_F];
```

**second array**

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $queryGemeinde );
```

**That's my foreach loop**

```
<?php foreach($results as $index => $print) { ?>
                <tr>    <!-- display data -->
                    <td width=<?php echo $width[0]; ?>><?php echo $print->postleitzahl; ?></td>
                    <td width=<?php echo $width[1]; ?>><?php echo $print->ort; ?></td>
                    <td width=<?php echo $width[1]; ?>><?php echo $gemeinden[$index]; ?></td>
                    <td width=<?php echo $width[1]; ?>><?php echo $gemeinden[$index]; ?></td>
                    <td width=<?php echo $width[1]; ?>><?php echo $gemeinden[$index]; ?></td>
                </tr>               
        <?php }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**That's the result**
[image]

It seems as if it is stucked. And it makes sense but how Can I tell the foreach loop to go further after the third `<td></td>`

Comment: Could  you share the output of `var_dump($results);` to further debug the case?

Comment: You can see the output on the picture. first two columns. There's not really a bug. Index is one and stays till the first loop is over. The index should do +1 and + 2 after each loop in order to get the next element in the array.

Comment: No, this is just the Html rendered by the foreach loop. You're trying to render more than 4 rows, so the first step would be to check if there are more than 4 rows in the result ;-)

Comment: *"go further after the third `<td></td>`"*: it already prints 5. Don't understand the question...

Comment: there are 20 rows and two columns from the $results
The output for the first row should be
24217 || Barsbek | 6 | 2 | 4

Comment: Please prove that claim (that there are 20 rows coming back from your query): what is the output of `count($results)`?

Comment: Your three last `td` are coded with exactly the same code: why would they print anything different? Why do you expect `$gemeinden[$index];` to be different from one statement to the next?

Comment: Exactly, that's my question. How can I tell the loop to go to next in the array

Comment: The loop will increment `$index` at the end of each iteration of the loop, but while you are in one iteration of the loop, `$index` will of course not change. I don't understand what you are after. You should clarify your question with actually data (in PHP format) and expected output for that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you need to fetch next item after 3rd `td` so you can use below approach:

```
<?php foreach($results as $index => $print) { ?>
                <tr>    <!-- display data -->
                    <td width=<?php echo $width[0]; ?>><?php echo $print->postleitzahl; ?></td>
                    <td width=<?php echo $width[1]; ?>><?php echo $print->ort; ?></td>
                    <td width=<?php echo $width[1]; ?>><?php echo $gemeinden[$index]; ?></td>
                    <?php $index++; ?>
                    <td width=<?php echo $width[1]; ?>><?php echo $gemeinden[$index]; ?></td>
                    <?php $index++; ?>
                    <td width=<?php echo $width[1]; ?>><?php echo $gemeinden[$index]; ?></td>
                </tr>               
        <?php }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Or you can even iterate loop as below as well:

```
<?php foreach($results as $index => $print) { ?>
                <tr>    <!-- display data -->
                    <td width=<?php echo $width[0]; ?>><?php echo $print->postleitzahl; ?></td>
                    <td width=<?php echo $width[1]; ?>><?php echo $print->ort; ?></td>
                    <?php foreach($gemeinden as $gemValue) { ?> 
                         <td width=<?php echo $width[1]; ?>><?php echo $gemValue; ?></td>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tr>               
        <?php }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope it helps you!!